# Weird Behavior in my Python Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

So this is pretty self explanatory.

```
class Tray(object):
    '''
    A class used to collect information about each unique tray
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.cycle = None
        self.cell = None
        self.bIsTilted = False # Assume trays are not tilted
        self.bSendNoData = False # Assume data is sent, modified later if data not sent
        self.trayData = (self.cycle,
                         self.cell,
                         self.bIsTilted,
                         self.bSendNoData)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.trayData)

    def setCycle(self, cycle):
        self.cycle = cycle

    def setCell(self, cell):
        self.cell = cell
```

If I run the following statements:

```
currentTray = Tray()
currentTray.setCycle(250)
currentTray.setCell(300)
print(currentTray)
currentTray.setCell(25)
print(currentTray.cell)
```

my output would be:

```
(None, None, False, False)
25
```

So, I guess I'm trying to figure out why my self.trayData isn't updating according to the values in self.cycle, self.cell etc. What's the problem here?

Comment: In Python, you don't typically define `setCycle` and `setCell` (which would more properly be named `set_cycle` and `set_cell`; camel case is conventionally reserved for class names), instead allowing the user to simply set the values of the attributes themselves.

Comment: You're right about my naming convention being off. But I definitely read somewhere that since Python doesn't technically allow 'private/public' variables, it's still the right approach to write accessors for your variables

Comment: @Asif: Nope.  You just let the end user modify things directly.  If you later need encapsulation, you create a property like Anand shows.  Properties can be writeable as well as readable.

Comment: To expand on Kevin's comment, properties form a nice middle ground; they look at attribute references, but behave like methods (and you can replace an attribute with a property without breaking code that assumed it was accessing an attribute directly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the following -

```
self.trayData = (self.cycle,
                 self.cell,
                 self.bIsTilted,
                 self.bSendNoData)
```

`self.trayData`'s first element does not point to `self.cycle` (atleast not in the way you want it to) , it points to the object `self.cycle` points to  , which is `None`. So when you set a new value to `self.cycle` it will not automatically reflect in `self.trayData` .

The easiest thing to do for your specific case to work is , to set `trayData` in both  `setCycle` as well as `setCell` methods.

Example -

```
def setCycle(self, cycle):
    self.cycle = cycle
    self.trayData = (self.cycle,
                 self.cell,
                 self.bIsTilted,
                 self.bSendNoData)
```

---

Or you can define `trayData` as a property instead of defining it in the `__init__()` method, Example -

```
class Tray(object):
    '''
    A class used to collect information about each unique tray
    '''
    @property
    def trayData(self):
        return (self.cycle, self.cell, self.bIsTilted, self.bSendNoData)
    .
    .
    . #rest of the class.
```

Then you can access trayData using `Tray().trayData` , using the object of `Tray` class.

Example/Demo -

```
In [94]: class Tray(object):
   ....:     @property
   ....:     def trayData(self):
   ....:         return (1,2,3,4)
   ....:

In [95]: t=Tray()

In [96]: t.trayData
Out[96]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you set `trayData` in `__init__` it's not getting updated each time the other functions are called. It would make more sense to make it a method of the class that returns the values:

```
def trayData():
    return (self.cycle, self.cell, self.bIsTilted, self.bSendNoData)
```

Comment: Even better, use the `@property` decorator.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you use `@property` decorator in this case. do you need to set a setter for it?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez no, because you wouldn't be setting traydata at all; it's a read-only property that aggregates other properties.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's a better suggestion. I'd edit my answer to include it but I haven't used decorators before and Anand's accepted answer already covers it.

Answer (score 1):

Python variables don't update like you're trying to do. You would need to do something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cycle = None
    self.cell = None
    self.bIsTilted = False # Assume trays are not tilted
    self.bSendNoData = False # Assume data is sent, modified later if data not sent
    self.trayData = (self.cycle,
                     self.cell,
                     self.bIsTilted,
                     self.bSendNoData)

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.trayData)

def setCycle(self, cycle):
    self.cycle = cycle
    self.trayData = (self.cycle,
                     self.cell,
                     self.bIsTilted,
                     self.bSendNoData)

def setCell(self, cell):
    self.cell = cell
    self.trayData = (self.cycle,
                     self.cell,
                     self.bIsTilted,
                     self.bSendNoData)
```

Basically, if you want `self.trayData` to have the latest data, you need to update it any time you update in the values in it.

Now, if you don't need to ever access `self.trayData` directly, you could just do:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return (self.cycle, self.cell, self.bIsTilted, self.bSendNoData)
```

Comment: That seems strange to me. Isn't the `self.cycle` variable in my setCycle() method the same as `self.cycle` in my __init__() method?

Comment: @Asif It is, but when you do `foo = bar`, `foo` just gets the value of `bar` at assignment time. It doesn't continue to point to `bar`.

Comment: This is my struggle when trying to working in C++ and python at the same time. I forget how variables work in each language :/